# Find pattern of unknown date string

Tags: java, date-parsing

Fairly new to Java but trying to figure out how to solve a problem I came across. I read through many articles on formatting unknown date/time in Java as I know you need to first know the pattern of the date before you can start to parse the date. Is there a way to given a String date such as `2/21/2019` that this method would return the format of this date string. 
I found ofPattern util but seems to only return the pattern of a format and not a string like above.

I was looking for something like the pseudo code below. If I am able to return the date pattern given the string I could then use SimpleDateFormat passing in my pattern dynamically.

```
String date = '2/21/2019';
Date datePattern = date.getPattern();
// datePattern would output ""MM/dd/yyyy""
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(datePattern);  
String strDate = formatter.format(date);
```

Thanks again,

Comment: `date.getPattern()` String doesn't *have* a getPattern method.

Comment: That was my pseudo code. I was expecting to find some sort of util to call on my String or Date.

Comment: Why do not use Java 8 Date api ? It is more eay to use.

Comment: I think in the comment, he's basically saying 'how would I get a method which would do something similar to this, where from a string, it returns the pattern'. The actual answer is basically that you can't -- even if you had a system to run through a whole nearly exhaustive list of patters, what do you do when you hit 03/02/01? I would tell you that is 3 February 2001, but others might disagree.

Comment: if date is 11/11/2019 how you know if is MM/dd/yyy or dd/MM/yy, or if date is 11/11/11

Comment: Is your set of options finite?  I have code that encounters a few different patterns, and luckily none are as similar as ifly6's good example of how a universal parser can fall down.  I attempt to parse each expected pattern and move on if the current pattern throws.

Comment: Yea, I am running into an instance where I don't know what the pattern of the date is and couldn't find a good solution to this format an unknown date to a standard format such as MM/dd/yyyy. But I do see how that would be hard to infer what the date should be which all the different formats of dates out there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a way to given a String date such as 2/21/2019 that this method would return the format of this date string.

No. Java cannot interpret the meaning of your strings. Many date string formats can be ambiguous. Is `1/2/3` the second of January of 2003, the first of February of 2003, or March 2nd of 2001?

Search Stack Overflow. You will find many Questions and Answers about parsing strings of various date-time formats, including [an Answer I wrote today](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54892558/642706).

- If you have unpredictable inputs, then of course no reliable solution is possible, only guesswork.
- If you can identify a limited set of non-ambiguous formats in use, then define a set of `DateTimeFormatter` objects. For any input, try each formatter in succession until one works (does not throw `DateTimeParseException`).

The real solution is to educate the publisher of your data about [ISO 8601](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601).

One last thing: Never use `SimpleDateFormat`. The terrible legacy date-time classes were supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes.